# Установка Windows 7 на планшет

Tags: windows, windows-7, tablet

Я хочу провести научный эксперимент и установить Win7 на планшет, на котором изначально стояла десятка. Я уже ставил на него восьмерку, разные версии десятки и даже AstraLinux (никому не советую, это ерунда полная). На очереди семерка. Делаю по вот этому [гайду](https://www.white-windows.ru/kak-ustanovit-windows-7-na-gpt-disk-universalnyj-sposob/), начиная с пункта 3 "Установка Win7 на пустой жёсткий диск". И все нормально проходит, никаких ошибок, но после перезагрузки получаю окошко с ошибкой "Windows Boot Manager boot failed":

[image: ошибка "Windows Boot Manager boot failed"]

Много всего перерыл в интернете, но таким никто не занимается и информации по конкретной проблеме нет. А другая информация не помогает. На планшете стоит проц Intel Atom ZF-что-то-там, не помню уже, x64 поддерживает; стоит 1гб ОЗУ, 14 с небольшим гигов ПЗУ. Пытаюсь поставить оригинальный образ винды, Windows 7 x64 Ultimate. Для всей процедуры использую OTG-шнурок, хаб на 4 порта, USB мышь и USB клавиатуру, две флешки: на одной WinPE от xemom1, на другой лежит образ винды.

И собственно мой вопрос: как эту ошибку починить, чтобы можно было загрузиться и продолжить установку?

Comment: Скорее всего Win7 поставить не получится. Я так же пытался поставить на ASUS x205t - ничего старше Win8 поставить не получилось.

Comment: @str4n9er а в чем проблема-то? Че оно не ставится? Вот [тут](https://superuser.com/questions/649997/install-windows-7-on-windows-8-tablet-possible) во втором ответе говорят, что такое возможно, лишь бы архитектура подходила. Звучит очень правдоподобно, как по мне

Comment: Скорее всего пробоема в сильно порезанном UEFI. Я бы начал оттуда копать.

Comment: @donRumata а как копать-то? Если UEFI неполноценный, то я с ним ничего не смогу сделать, так ведь?

Comment: Если сможешь вызвать сервисное меню планшета - наверняка сможешь и uefi ковырунть. Из ОС же доступ есть.

Comment: @donRumata ну, на esc открывается менюшка, да. А что ковырять-то?

Comment: Я когда ставил линь на него, наткнулся на вот [этот](https://askubuntu.com/questions/775498/ubuntu-on-32-bit-uefi-only-based-tablet-pc) вопрос. С файликом bootia32.efi все должно работать, но где такой найти для windows?

Comment: @str4n9er [вот почему](http://www.outsidethebox.ms/questions/question/%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-x86-%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D1%8C%D1%8E%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80-%D1%81-uefi#sabai-entity-content-85) не получается поставить ничего старше Win8

Comment: @Moongod вин7 можно из под uefi установить. Правда, может оказаться непобедимым поиск драйверов

Comment: Ну так там написано, что с 64 проблем нет.

Comment: Win7 поддерживает UEFI только в 64 битном варианте и для этого нужен UEFI x64, а у меня x32 UEFI на планшете(((((((

Comment: Есть такая штука как `EDK II`. https://github.com/tianocore/edk2 Можешь попробовать её прикрутить.

Comment: @donRumata это кастомный UEFI, что ли? Хмммм.... Начал гуглить, инфы маловато и все на английском. Трудновато на английском, но возможно. Изучу завтра и расскажу о своих продвижениях

Comment: @Moongod хм, а что? У uefi ещё бывает разрядность разная? Почему вы так решили?

Comment: @Александр [тут](http://www.outsidethebox.ms/questions/question/установка-x86-системы-на-компьютер-с-uefi#sabai-entity-content-85) так написано, к середине ответа есть объяснение о том, что на UEFI x32 можно поставить только х32 систему и точно так же на UEFI x64 только х64 систему

Answer (score 4, accepted):

После проведенного небольшого исследования, стало ясно, что эта ошибка появлялась потому что я ставил x64 редакцию Win7, а UEFI на моем планшете не поддерживает x64 системы. А x32 редакция Win7 не поддерживает загрузку в UEFI. На мой планшет можно поставить только Win8 и Win10 в x32 редакциях.

Answer (score 3):

Вы молодец, конечно...

Но данные действия не рекомендованы производителем не только потому, что нет дров и есть шанс что планшет не запустит ОСь, но и по более важной проблеме - железо.

В планшетах не используется SSD, там ставят обычно распаянный SSD, или если быть точным - тупо впаивают eMMC чип в мат. плату.

Что такое чип eMMC - это чип, который имеет разделенную пинами (под пузом) память.

Часть памяти отвечает за загрузчик, часть за жесткую память, а часть - кусок EFI BIOS.

А сейчас самое интересное - хоть с разных пинов должен обеспечиваться доступ только к определенным разделам - вся инфа кристалла хранится в единой системе памяти, одной кристалле. И, когда мы ставим, например, винду - мы видим дохера разделов, часть из которых даже не обнаружается - если изменим (удалим или изменим размер) хоть один раздел - возрастает вероятность того, что встроенный контроллер перестанет считывать по одному из пинов нужный раздел - и как итог можем повредить часть EFI BIOS, которая храница в блока 0-2 и получить кирпич без BIOS.

Для восстановления же придется выпаивать чип, прошивать его и впаивать обратно, что стоит вы районе 30к

Comment: Интересная информация, но я уже перестал мучаться с семеркой...
P.s. 30к? Дай бог, чтобы сам этот планшет больше 5к стоил)

Comment: @Moongod ага, где-то так. Оборудование для замены намного-намного дороже стоит, а заказов мало - потому и цены в сервисных центах - огого

Comment: И да - я когда-то так убил Samsung Ativ Smart PC 500t1c